# JHipster: Receive 401 Unauthorized when testing microservices

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, jwt, jhipster

I generated simple microservices application with Jhipster I wrote simple controller like hello world,
When I am trying to test through test method it is always giving Unauthorized error and the test fails.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController{
  @GetMapping("/test/{Id}")
  public String TestGetData(@PathVariable int Id) {
      return "Here is your data!";
  }
}
```

Testclass:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = HerstellerController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestIT {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

private static final long ONE_MINUTE = 60000;

private String token;
private Key key;
private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    tokenProvider = new TokenProvider( new JHipsterProperties());
    key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64
        .decode("xxxx"));

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(tokenProvider, "key", key);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(tokenProvider, "tokenValidityInMilliseconds", ONE_MINUTE);
}

@Test
public void TestData() throws Exception {

    token=tokenProvider.createToken(createAuthentication(),false);
    String id="1";

    String expData = "Here is your data!";
    String result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/test/"+ id)
        .header("Authorization","Bearer " + token))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn()
        .getResponse()
        .getContentAsString();
    System.out.println("\nResult:\n"+result);
}

private Authentication createAuthentication() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN));
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin", authorities);
}
```

Changed the securityconfig also like this

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").anonymous()
```

Comment: can you show the generated token?

Comment: Generated Token:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOIiwiZXhwIjoxNTc0OTI4NTY4fQ.cq3EB07WDpR5tvlKRAaddumHpkyGVYXuzZ3BOyRp33XmoPbomNHTPI59QNDeOAYaWx_cFEPb7VtTPdwEJEr6tA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added authentication to securityContext in setup of Testclass!, It works!

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(createAuthentication());
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```